# issue while resizing UISegmented Control as LeftBarButtonItem in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

While changing the width of UIView, the UISegmentedControl (as leftbarbuttonitem) with three buttons overlaps the navigationbar title, and when changed to the previous width the third button in segmentedcontrol is not working.How this leftbarbuttonitem autoresize causes problem with its width.

Answer (score 0):

will you change the view size often??

you set Bool for that like

**implement this in .h file**

```
  Bool ifViewChange;
```

**implement this in .m file**

**set the value to yes where the view change**

```
ifViewChange=YES;

if(ifViewChange)
{
   // Mention the button sizes
   ifViewChange=NO;
}
else 
{
//Normal size
}
```

Comment: Thanku for your suggestion. But that way is not possible in my case. The problem is solved by adding a UILabel as titleview and setting this property [titleLab setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth] for UILabel and changed its rect also.